# How to implement iAd correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I am trying to get my banner ad to display but i receive the following error:

Property 'canDisplayBannerAds' not found on object of type 'ViewController *'

Thing you may need to know

1. My app deployment target is iOS 6

Here is the code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
[Tramresult setNumberOfLines:0];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the iAd Framework to your build libraries.

Include this in your **.h** file

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
```

Include this in **viewDidLoad** of **.m** file.

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed the #import <iAd/iAd.h> part